# What is the best way to make my DbContext class inaccessible in the controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, controller, dbcontext

I am building a Web application with ASP.NET and I have made two separate projects within one solution of which one is the ASP.NET project and the other one a 'Console Application' called data layer. In the data layer I have connected it with my local db (ADO.NET entity framework database first).

My question is, I want my DbContext class to be inaccessible in the controllers within my ASP.NET project. Currently it is still reachable by just 'using data layer'. I have a folder in my ASP.NET with builder classes and they can reach the DbContext, I only want the builders to reach my DbContext. So in my controller I only want to use my builders to do something with the DbContext.

**Example of how I want it:**

```
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
         return View(new ExampleBuilder().GetListFromDb());
    }
```

**And not (this must be forbidden and inaccessible within my project):**

```
private DbContext db = new DbContext();

public ActionResult Index() 
{
   return View(db.SomeModel.ToList());
}
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following project structure

- `Web` (Depends on Data.Repositories and Common)
- `Data.Repositories` (Depends on Data.Model and Common) - here you implement repositories that use your EntityFramework context from Data.Model.
- `Data.Model` (Depends on Common) - put your EntityFramework context class here, but all the models should go into Common to make them available for all projects.
- `Common` - your EntityFramework models and everything else that needs to be accessible everywhere e.g. exceptions, utils.

Basically your repository methods would look like that:

```
public Common.User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    using (var context = new Data.Model.MyContext())
    {
        return context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Email == email);
    }
}
```

Your web doesn't have a reference to Data.Model and it will not be able to use your context class directly. It will have to go through the Repositories abstraction layer.

Comment: So my web is a ASP.NET project, Data.Repositories and the other 2 are just Console Applications?

Comment: @elcommandante don't use `Console Application` type. Instead there is a `Class Library` project. It's about the same but when you use console app type it means that there is a startup entrance point Program.Main(), I believe you don't need it.

Comment: thank you! I'm currently working on my solution structure to make this all possible. I''ll comment as soon as this works out for me.

Comment: I have added the Class Libraries and I have the structure like this:
Web - contains Builders and Controllers
Commons - contains Models that passes data to the real object of Context class
Data.Model - contains the Db.edmx and my DbContext and DbContextPartial (this contains the GenericRepository class from Data.Repositories)
Data.Repositories - contains IGenericRepository and GenericRepository.

I have a Data.Model reference within the Data.Repository. But now the DbContextPartial can't refer to the GenericRepository. And also my Web can't refer to the Data.Model db objects. Solution?

Comment: @elcommandante if you do your app from scratch, you shouldn't use edmx context. It's an old approach. You need to use latest Entity Framework version and most likely `Code First` approach. It is way more flexible in terms of building overall architecture.

Comment: Personally I prefer Code First approach, but since the company I work for is using Database First, I focus on that. By the way, I think I kinda fixed it but I face another issue. I have my builders placed in the Common because otherwise the controller in my Web can have direct access to the DbContext. My Data_Model has the Repositories reference, common has Data_Model reference and my Web has Common reference, so it can approach the builder and light models. The issue now is that the builder can't have System.Web references because it is not a web project within the solution.

Comment: So without that System.Web reference, it can't use the classes like HttpPostedFileBase. Do you have any advice? @Andrei M

Comment: @elcommandante it's not an issue at all if Common uses `System.Web`. Regarding EntityFramework: I think you still can do database first but without ugly edmx context. Try to use latest visual studio and `Install-Package EntityFramework` and go from there.